# Filter duplicate logs on datadog dashboard

Tags: datadog

I hope you are well,

I'm working on a dashboard, which brings up error logs from different instances.

The problem is that I end up with a lot of duplicate lines, because an error can come up several times in a row. But this makes the dashboard unreadable.

Is it possible to filter, keeping for example only one line (I only get the last one, depending on the time)

Ty for your help

[image]

Answer (score 1):

These are, technically, not duplicates but individual events, due to the different timestamp each one has.

However, datadog allows for multiple types of groupings to end up with the information you are looking for.

Consult the following tutorial:
https://docs.datadoghq.com/logs/explorer/group/